# How to crop a Bitmap which is set on ImageView (Custom Crop instead of default crop)?

Tags: android, bitmap

I tried searching for a custom crop activity, but most of them lead to the default "com.android.camera.action.CROP". Can any one please help me to find a solution for creating a custom crop functionality.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fr_editcrop, container, false);

        photo = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.photo);

        tmp = getArguments().getString("PHOTO");

        byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode(tmp,Base64.DEFAULT);
        bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
        photo.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [picasso image libary](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for this.It has too many ready made method for resize,crop,Fit etc.You can set image directly ti imageview from url.Hope it will help.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.xyz);
resizedBitmap =Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, x, y, width, height);`

x The x coordinate of the first pixel in source

y The y coordinate of the first pixel in source

width The number of pixels in each row

height The number of rows

Comment: What's the difference in your and my answer?

Answer (score 0):

As discussed with Nilesh Patel,  he is trying to create a custom crop, instead of using the default "com.android.camera.action.CROP". i just want to share this piece of code that will provide the custom crop or freehand crop activity for image view. hopefully it will help you guys.

First you need to create a class like CropView

```
public class CropView extends ImageView {

 Paint paint = new Paint();
 private int initial_size = 300;
 private static Point leftTop, rightBottom, center, previous;

 private static final int DRAG= 0;
 private static final int LEFT= 1;
 private static final int TOP= 2;
 private static final int RIGHT= 3;
 private static final int BOTTOM= 4;

 private int imageScaledWidth,imageScaledHeight;
 // Adding parent class constructors   
 public CropView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initCropView();
 }

 public CropView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
     super(context, attrs, 0);
     initCropView();
 }

 public CropView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
     super(context, attrs, defStyle);
     initCropView();
 }

 @Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
 {
     super.onDraw(canvas);
     if(leftTop.equals(0, 0))
         resetPoints();
     canvas.drawRect(leftTop.x, leftTop.y, rightBottom.x, rightBottom.y, paint);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
     int eventaction = event.getAction();
     switch (eventaction) { 
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
             previous.set((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
             break; 
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 
             if(isActionInsideRectangle(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
                 adjustRectangle((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
                 invalidate(); // redraw rectangle
                 previous.set((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
             }
             break; 
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
             previous = new Point();
             break;
     }         
     return true;
 }

 private void initCropView() {
     paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
     paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
     paint.setStrokeWidth(5);  
     leftTop = new Point();
     rightBottom = new Point();
     center = new Point();
     previous = new Point();
 }

 public void resetPoints() {
     center.set(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);
     leftTop.set((getWidth()-initial_size)/2,(getHeight()-initial_size)/2);
     rightBottom.set(leftTop.x+initial_size, leftTop.y+initial_size);
 }

 private static boolean isActionInsideRectangle(float x, float y) {
     int buffer = 10;
     return (x>=(leftTop.x-buffer)&&x<=(rightBottom.x+buffer)&& y>=(leftTop.y-buffer)&&y<=(rightBottom.y+buffer))?true:false;
 }

 private boolean isInImageRange(PointF point) {
     // Get image matrix values and place them in an array
     float[] f = new float[9];
     getImageMatrix().getValues(f);

     // Calculate the scaled dimensions
     imageScaledWidth = Math.round(getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth() * f[Matrix.MSCALE_X]);
     imageScaledHeight = Math.round(getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight() * f[Matrix.MSCALE_Y]);

     return (point.x>=(center.x-(imageScaledWidth/2))&&point.x<=(center.x+(imageScaledWidth/2))&&point.y>=(center.y-(imageScaledHeight/2))&&point.y<=(center.y+(imageScaledHeight/2)))?true:false;
 }

 private void adjustRectangle(int x, int y) {
     int movement;
     switch(getAffectedSide(x,y)) {
         case LEFT:
             movement = x-leftTop.x;
             if(isInImageRange(new PointF(leftTop.x+movement,leftTop.y+movement)))
                leftTop.set(leftTop.x+movement,leftTop.y+movement);
            break;
        case TOP:
            movement = y-leftTop.y;
            if(isInImageRange(new PointF(leftTop.x+movement,leftTop.y+movement)))
                leftTop.set(leftTop.x+movement,leftTop.y+movement);
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            movement = x-rightBottom.x;
            if(isInImageRange(new PointF(rightBottom.x+movement,rightBottom.y+movement)))
                rightBottom.set(rightBottom.x+movement,rightBottom.y+movement);
            break;
        case BOTTOM:
            movement = y-rightBottom.y;
            if(isInImageRange(new PointF(rightBottom.x+movement,rightBottom.y+movement)))
                rightBottom.set(rightBottom.x+movement,rightBottom.y+movement);
            break;      
        case DRAG:
            movement = x-previous.x;
            int movementY = y-previous.y;
            if(isInImageRange(new PointF(leftTop.x+movement,leftTop.y+movementY)) && isInImageRange(new PointF(rightBottom.x+movement,rightBottom.y+movementY))) {
                leftTop.set(leftTop.x+movement,leftTop.y+movementY);
                rightBottom.set(rightBottom.x+movement,rightBottom.y+movementY);
            }
            break;
    }
}

private static int getAffectedSide(float x, float y) {
    int buffer = 10;
    if(x>=(leftTop.x-buffer)&&x<=(leftTop.x+buffer))
        return LEFT;
    else if(y>=(leftTop.y-buffer)&&y<=(leftTop.y+buffer))
        return TOP;
    else if(x>=(rightBottom.x-buffer)&&x<=(rightBottom.x+buffer))
        return RIGHT;
    else if(y>=(rightBottom.y-buffer)&&y<=(rightBottom.y+buffer))
        return BOTTOM;
    else
        return DRAG;
}

public byte[] getCroppedImage() {
    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable)getDrawable();
    float x = leftTop.x-center.x+(drawable.getBitmap().getWidth()/2);
    float y = leftTop.y-center.y+(drawable.getBitmap().getHeight()/2);
    Bitmap cropped = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getBitmap(),(int)x,(int)y,(int)rightBottom.x-(int)leftTop.x,(int)rightBottom.y-(int)leftTop.y);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    cropped.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
  }
 }
```

What i did was, i extended the ImageView and added Cropping powers. It is pretty easy to use. Once the class is saved, just use it in the layout like this.

```
  <"your package name".CropView
    android:id="@+id/image_preview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And call this Crop View in your activity  like below

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 setContentView(R.layout.crop_layout);


    myCropView = new CropView(this);

    tmp = getArguments().getString("PHOTO");

      byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode(tmp,Base64.DEFAULT);
      bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
      myCropView.setImageBitmap(bmp);

 }
```

Thats it! Hope it helps! If you encounter any problem, please feel free to ask :)